# Constrain mouse cursor to line

Tags: cocoa, events, mouse

I'm wondering if it's possible to accurately constrain my mouse cursor to a line. The general idea is that I want to create a ruler/french curve app where I can drag out a line and make it as curvy as I want with bezier points, and then hold down a hotkey to constrain my mouse to it so I can paint a similar line in photoshop with a wacom tablet.

What i've tried so far is the following. I'm just testing it with a diagonal line right now. While it does seem to properly constrain my mouse to the line, when I draw a line in photoshop, it looks like there are mouse events that are dispatched in between the events that "snap" my cursor to my diagonal. For instance, if I move my mouse really fast up and to the right, the mouse will move up and to the right for a single event loop and then snap back to my diagonal. This obviously isn't going to work for painting purposes. Is there some lower level mouse interface that I can tap into to intercept ALL mouse events and possibly prevent them from being dispatched before they are sent to other applications.

```
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSMouseMovedMask handler:^(NSEvent * mouseEvent) {
    [self mouseMoved:mouseEvent];
}];
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSLeftMouseDraggedMask handler:^(NSEvent * mouseEvent) {
    [self mouseMoved:mouseEvent];
}];


- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)evt {
    NSLog(@"Mouse moved: %@", NSStringFromPoint([evt locationInWindow]));

    NSPoint mousePos = [evt locationInWindow];

    CGSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval(0.0f);
    CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(CGPointMake(mousePos.x, mousePos.x));
}
```

Comment: I want to achieve something similar, but with a GUI windows software. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [CGEventTap API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html).